# Please send an email announcement *before* the deletion of the proposal

Tags: feature-request, area-51

The proposal "Teaching and Tutoring: Math and Science" was recently deleted due to inactivity.

It is rather annoying to get the email announcement of the deletion after the fact because I would like to be able to copy the information.

Why could you not send an email: "Proposal X will be deleted due to inactivity in a week?" ?

I do not want to protest the deletion, but I want to access the sample questions.

Comment: It would also give you some time to try to drum up some more support.

Answer (score 6):

The email you received wasn't a *notice-after-the-fact* of a deletion. It was a *heads up* to let you know there is a [related, more-successful proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23685/educators) you may wish to support. The disparate, education-related proposals are not gaining traction *because* support is spread to thin, so combining forces into a larger, more-comprehensive site is a useful tactic to getting those subjects launched.

As for sending deletion notices *before* cleaning out abandoned proposals — No, I don't see the value in artificially rousting support for a proposal that has had ABSOLUTELY NO ACTIVITY for 1-2 months; no new questions, no comments, no voting, nothing.

Getting a site started and making it successful in the long term **takes a lot of work and *dedicated* attention.** If we geared this system to constantly prod people *"please, please continue to pay attention to this struggling proposal"*, that is not likely to create a very promising site.

It's not a judgement call on whether a proposal was a good idea. Sometimes you simply do not have the right people with the right knowledge in the right place at the right time; so the momentum simply is not there to create a successful site. And sometimes the process falls apart when it *should* fall apart, as was the case here of splintering support across niche educational interests at the expense of a much more comprehensive, stronger site.

Comment: Have you actually read my question? Or do you just prefer to answer the comment from someone else below my question instead of my question? I don't want to avoid the deletion, I want to copy the deleted content that interests me before deletion. I visit all the proposals I follow very often even though I don't see the point of making regular comments all the time if the proposal just isn't viable. I did make a purely activity-oriented comment on my own proposal and I think that this is actually ridiculous that this will keep it alive.

Comment: @user9325: I see, your request is different. My bad. But the reasoning *not* to do that routinely is based on the same logic. Users ask to pull back questions from the failed proposal just to re-post them a second time around. I don't see that as something to encourage. But regarding your specific request, I have un-deleted the proposal so you can copy whatever you wish. I will keep it around until later this weekend. Enjoy.